# Angularjs - http get return html text instead json

Tags: json, spring, angularjs, http

My web app is using angularjs with spring mvc. When hosted in localhost the http get works fine in all browsers. But once hosted in a diferent server the http get returns the html of main tenplate page as result instead json.This wrong happen only chrome. No erros show in browser console. Someone can help me.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);

angular.module('myModule').factory('myService', function($http, $q, CONTEXT_APP) {
    return {

        getPromiseFunction: function(id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(CONTEXT_APP + '/mvc/id/' + id).success(function(result){
                deferred.resolve(result);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

angular.module('myControllerModule').controller('SecondController', function($scope, $routeParams, myService) {


    var promise = myService.getPromiseFunction($routeParams.id);
    promise then(function(result) {
       $scope.result = result;
    });
});
```

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with your server setup.  Have you used a network sniffer to watch the packets and compare differences in packets between your localhost setup vs the different server setup?

Comment: If you don't explicitly state the desired format when making the request, the server "guesses" based on the requesting program.  Likely the server doesn't have a default "guess" for Chrome.  You need to explicitly state in your request what format you want.  (Unfortunately, I can't give you chapter and verse on what to do -- I just know the problem exists.)